# ubuntu-bug packagename, what is the package name for laptop keyboard-layout bugs?

Tags: 14.04, keyboard-layout, launchpad, bug-reporting

I have Ubuntu 14.04.

I have a Swedish laptop keyboard and the Ubuntu language is English.

Every time I restart the computer the keyboard-layout switches away from Swedish keyboard-layout to English keyboard-layout, but the Swedish keyboard-layout is shown as selected, but it's actually the English one that is used. So after each restart I have to select the Swedish keyboard-layout option, even though it's already shown as selected at the top bar in Ubuntu.

My question is when I run the command ubuntu-bug packagename, what package name should I report the bug under?

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar question (but for Ubuntu 20.04) in wanting to submit a keyboard layout bug.

I found https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKeyboardDetection which stated that:

> Keyboard related bugs should initially be filed against **xorg**, as bugbot will switch it to the correct package (ex. `xserver-xorg-input-evdev`). If the bug turns out to be a kernel bug or a bug in another package, bug triagers can assign the bug additionally to that package and mark the `xserver-xorg-input-evdev` task as invalid.

I filed my bug using `ubuntu-bug` and choosing **Display (X.org)**.

I believe that laptop hardware keyboard bugs are *not* meant to be filed under the `ubuntu-keyboard` package as one might expect, because that is apparently for on-screen keyboards (and not installed by default in my clean Ubuntu 20.04 installation, even though I've seen one pop up in the login screen when I'm using the laptop's touchscreen).